# Moving MysQL data directory error: Can't create test file mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to move mysql datadir to another location on external drive which is formatted with ext4. I'm betting following error:

```
# lsblk -f
..

sdb                                                                                       
└─sdb1 ext4     1.0   kingston960     33613c4b-3ef5-4727-abdf-bbf00f7dcc98  810.1G     3% /var/lib/mysql
                                                                                          /media/satya/kingston

# cat /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf | grep datadir
datadir = /media/satya/kingston/mysql

# ls -l /media/satya/kingston/
drwxrwxrwx 7 mysql mysql  4096 Feb  7 19:29 mysql

root@satya:/media/satya/kingston/mysql# ls -l
total 79316
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql       56 Feb  7 15:40  auto.cnf
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql      180 Feb  7 15:40  binlog.000001
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql      180 Feb  7 15:40  binlog.000002
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql      180 Feb  7 15:44  binlog.000003
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql      180 Feb  7 15:48  binlog.000004
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql      180 Feb  7 19:29  binlog.000005
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql       80 Feb  7 19:29  binlog.index
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1709 Feb  7 15:40  ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     1112 Feb  7 15:40  ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     1112 Feb  7 15:40  client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1705 Feb  7 15:40  client-key.pem
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   196608 Feb  7 19:29 '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  8585216 Feb  7 15:40 '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql     3382 Feb  7 19:29  ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Feb  7 19:29  ibdata1
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb  7 19:29 '#innodb_redo'
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb  7 19:29 '#innodb_temp'
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb  7 15:40  mysql
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 26214400 Feb  7 19:29  mysql.ibd
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb  7 15:40  performance_schema
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1705 Feb  7 15:40  private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql      452 Feb  7 15:40  public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     1112 Feb  7 15:40  server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql     1705 Feb  7 15:40  server-key.pem
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb  7 15:40  sys
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 16777216 Feb  7 19:29  undo_001
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 16777216 Feb  7 19:29  undo_002

# sudo systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.

#tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log

2024-02-08T13:08:36.964135Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /media/satya/kingston/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2024-02-08T13:08:36.964221Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 37345
2024-02-08T13:08:36.969570Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /media/satya/kingston/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2024-02-08T13:08:36.969582Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /media/satya/kingston/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

#journalctl -xeu mysql.service

The job identifier is 10419.
Feb 08 13:08:39 satya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Subject: Unit process exited
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
 
 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Feb 08 13:08:39 satya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 13:08:39 satya systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
 
 The job identifier is 10419 and the job result is failed.
Feb 08 13:08:40 satya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
 Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
 the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Feb 08 13:08:40 satya systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
 Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
 
 The job identifier is 10504 and the job result is done.
Feb 08 13:08:40 satya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 08 13:08:40 satya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 13:08:40 satya systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
 
 The job identifier is 10504 and the job result is failed.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the old path is still used in the `mysql.service` file.

Comment: No, that's not true. I've verified it many times by switching between old path and new path.

Comment: I would have verified it by looking at the unit file contents, but what do I know...

Comment: Is that device being moved between Windows and Linux?  That is, was it "formatted" by one OS, but being used by the other?